# Download Attribute in anchor tag not work in IE9?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to working foe download canvas image. I used the anchor tag and in which used download attribute. It would be work proper in all browser but In IE9 it gives an error. Below display error show in console portion.

ERROR: 
SCRIPT122: The data area passed to a system call is too small.

```
var link = document.getElementById('cropImageLink');
link.setAttribute('download', 'MintyPaper.png');
link.setAttribute('href', c.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream"));
link.click();
```

Comment: yes, Any solution for edit download in IE9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download attribute is not supported by IE.
**[For more info](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download)**